# Tree not expanding if I change the children's property name in data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was working on a simple tree where I changed the naming convention in data. But the tree isn't expanding onto the levels anymore.

Here's is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d7nuv053/2/

The data I'm using is below:

```
{
  "data" :
  {
    "major" : "Grand Pa",
    "minor" : [
      {
        "major": "Pa",
        "minor": [
          {
          "major":"son"
        }
        ]
      },
      {
        "major": "afa",
        "minor":[
          {
            "major":"blah"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tree generator expects to see an object's property named `children`. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Tree-Layout.md#children):

> If children is not specified, returns the current children accessor function, which by default assumes that the input data is an object with a children array:
>
> ```
> function children(d) {
>       return d.children;
> }
> ```

So, you have to tell the tree generator that you have `minor` instead of `children`:

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width])
    .children(function(d){ 
        return d.minor; 
    });
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5h64f633/

And here as an Stack snippet:

```js
 var flare = {
  "data" :
  {
    "major" : "Grand Pa",
    "minor" : [
      {
        "major": "Pa",
        "minor": [
          {
          "major":"son"
        }
        ]
      },
      {
        "major": "afa",
        "minor":[
          {
            "major":"blah"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

 
 var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width])
 .children(function(d){ return d.minor});

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



root = flare.data;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function collapse(d) {
  if (d.minor) {
    d._minor = d.minor;
    d._minor.forEach(collapse);
    d.minor = null;
  }
}

root.minor.forEach(collapse);
update(root);


d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

// Compute the new tree layout.
var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

// Normalize for fixed-depth.
nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

// Update the nodes…
var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
// Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
    .on("click", click);

nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._minor ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.minor || d._minor ? -10 : 10; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.minor || d._minor ? "end" : "start"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.major; })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

// Transition nodes to their new position.
var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._minor ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
    .remove();

nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

// Update the links…
var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
      return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
    });

// Transition links to their new position.
link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
      return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
    })
    .remove();

// Stash the old positions for transition.
nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.y0 = d.y;
});
}

// Toggle minor on click.
function click(d) {
if (d.minor) {
  d._minor = d.minor;
  d.minor = null;
} else {
  d.minor = d._minor;
  d._minor = null;
}
update(d);
}
```

```css
.node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```